# Почему иконки в bottom navigation bar стали чёрно-белые

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view, иконки

В макете был прописан дизайн с цветными иконками

[image]

При реализации были импортированы в xml файлы иконки в папку drawbel. Там они отображаются нормально. Но в bottom navigation bar они стали чёрно-белыми. Можно ли это как-то исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]